# Unable to display content of 3 dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a PHP shopping cart in the $_SESSION array and I am trying to display it's content.
Here is my relevant code (i have a `session_start` at the beginning of my page):

```
if (isset($_GET['item']))
    {
        $item = $_GET['item'];

        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) 
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$item]))
        {

            $_SESSION['cart'][$item]['quantity']++; 

            echo "<h3 class=changement> Additional Item ".$item." has been added to cart.</h3>";
        }
        else
        {   
            $_SESSION ['cart'][$item]['quantity']= 1;

            echo "<h3 class=changement> Item ".$item." has been added to cart.</h3>";
        }

       foreach($_SESSION['cart'][$item] as $myItem => $myQuantity)
       {
           echo "<br> item: ".$myItem." quantity: ".$myQuantity."<br>";
       }
```

The foreach to display the contents of the cart does not display the name of the item.
The contents of the `$myItem` is always: quantity. Like so:

```
item: quantity quantity: 10
```

I would like the foreach to print:

```
item: Banana quantity: 4
item: Apple  quantity: 6
```

Obviously, there is something that I'm not getting about multi-dimensional arrays.
    Can someone clear this up.

Note: I am aware that instead of using this line : `$_SESSION['cart'][$item]['quantity']++;` 
    I could use just `$_SESSION['cart'][$item]++;` and have the item name as a integer variable to increment but I'm trying to understand
    how multi-dimensionnal arrays work with php.

```
Array ( 
   [connectee] => rush, 
   [start] => 1419894221, 
   [expire] => 1419894281,
   [cart] => Array ( 
       [troutster] => Array ( 
           [quantity] => 2 
       ) 
       [funny_man] => Array ( 
           [quantity] => 1 
       ) 
       [Gareth] => Array ( 
           [quantity] => 1 
       ) 
   ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you `print_r` your `$_SESSION` array and add it your question?  I bet just doing that might answer your question.

Comment: @dan08 Contents of $_SESSION with print_r:

'Array ( [connectee] => rush [start] => 1419894221 [expire] => 1419894281 [cart] => Array ( [troutster] => Array ( [quantity] => 2 ) [funny_man] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) [Gareth] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) ) )'

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemName => $item) {
    echo "<br> item: ".$myItem." quantity: ".$item["quantity"]."<br>";
}
```

Because $item is an object, and $_SESSION['cart'] is the array that you want to show

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $myItem => $myQuantity)
       {           
           foreach($myQuantity as $value)
           {
               echo "<br> item: ".$myItem." quantity: ".$value."<br>";
           }
       }
```

`$myQuantity` was an array, so I had to access it as such.